# Can Visual Studio 2013 debug clientside javascript in a NodeJs Web Application

Tags: node.js, debugging, visual-studio-2013, typescript

Debugging a ASP.NET WebAplication in Visual Studio 2013 gives the possibility to debug the clientside javascript files in Visual Studio 2013. Isn't this possible with a NodeJs Web Application in Visual Studio 2013 ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It can be done using IE as the browser and using node.js tools for Visual Studio, but I have not been able to debug through from client to server side code like you can with an ASP.Net project :o(

Anyhow, here is how you do it:

1. In IE, enable script debugging by going to Tools > Internet Options > Advanced Tab and clearing the "Disable script debugging flag". I think you have to restart IE for this to take effect
2. In VS2013 start your node.js project without debugging (Debug > Start without debugging or CTRL-F5)
3. In IE, attach to the VS debugger (View menu > External Script Debugger > Open. This should create a window that lets you attach IE to your instance of VS2013.

Comment: Thank you , it works. only you can't debug the serverside code simultaniously.